# RDP Ошибка отсутствия лицензии

Tags: windows, rdp

Текст ошибки:

> **Подключение к удалённому рабочему столу**
>
> Удалённый сеанс отключен, поскольку для данного компьютера отсутствуют клиентские лицензии удалённого рабочего стола.
>
> Обратитесь к администратору сервера.

Гугление проблемы выдает решение почистить ветку реестра `HKLM\software\microsoft\Mslicensing` с последующим запуском RDP от администратора. Пробовал в различных вариантах  — всё без толку.

На удаленной машине 1 общая лицензия. Коллеги подключаются без проблем. На моей машине данная ошибка наблюдается только с данным подключением. К другим машинам по RDP подключаюсь без проблем.

Моя ОС — Win10 Pro.

Собственно вопрос: Как исправить проблему с подключением?

Comment: Зачем реестр ломать? Написано же `Обратитесь к администратору`

Comment: Админы удалённой машины не шарят что не так. Мол проблема на вашей стороне, разбирайтесь сами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По какой-то, не совсем мне понятной, причине после удаления ветки `HKLM\software\microsoft\Mslicensing` она не восстанавливалась полностью в том виде, в котором была до удаления (не создавалась папка LICENSE000). Любые комбинации перезагрузки/запуска от администратора и тп. результатов не давали.

Что в итоге помогло: поднял виртуалку, на ней РДП подключился без проблем, после скопировал полностью ветку `HKLM\software\microsoft\Mslicensing` с виртуальной машины на рабочую. Далее перезагрузка и запуск RDP от администратора и подключение прошло успешно. Ещё пару запусков не от админстратора вылетала ошибка сертификата, но после повторной перезагрузки и запуска от адм. исчезла.

Answer (score 6):

После удаления ветки 
`HKLM\software\microsoft\Mslicensing` перезгружались сразу?
После перезагрузки не подключаясь, сразу можно зайти в реестр и посмотреть, есть ли эта ветка. ЕЕ там не должно быть до первого подключения к RDP. Возможно она у вас по факту не удаляется.

Так же как вариант можно выполнить
`reg delete "HKLMSOFTWAREMicrosoftMSLicensingStoreLICENSE000" /f`
Поправьте ключ под свой номер только.

Ну и стоило бы глянуть, как сервер раздает лицензии, возможно с его стороны какой-то косяк с кешем.

UP. так же можно попробовать в качестве эксперимента запустить RDP из под сеанса другого пользователя.

Comment: Да, после перезагрузки отсутствие ветки в реестре проверял. Причём, что до удаления ветки в ней присутствовали ключи лицензии (в папке Store) а после удаления они там не создаются вовсе, но на неверный ключ ругается. 

Как глянуть как сервер раздаёт лицензии?

Comment: Какая битность у вашей системы кстати? Возможно указываете неверный путь до ветки :) проверьте на всякий случай руками. У 64 битной системы будет примерно так:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSLicensing`
Первый запуск RDP после удаления ветки кстаи, обязательно производится от админа.

Comment: система х64, но в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ папки MSLicensin‌​g нет...

Comment: под другим пользователем пробовали?

Comment: Под другим пользователем та же петрушка была...

Answer (score 1):

По поводу 1 общая лицензия: у Вас на сервере лицензирования какая лицензия активирована на пользователя или на устройство, какое количество?
Если приобреталась лицензия на устройство, то необходимо проверить в 'Диспетчер лицензирования удаленных рабочих столов' к какому ПЭВМ привязана лицензия, с сколько свободных.
Лицензия на устройство не может быть использована для подключения к серверу с двух разных ПЭВМ.
Ну и как уже говорили, если у Вас отсутствуют права администратора, обратитесь к администратору сервера терминалов.
Общие рекомендации:

1. Проверить количество доступных лицензий терминального подключения.
   в зависимости от версии сервера способы могут отличаться, но в общем случае:
   a. зайти на сервер терминальных лицензий (чаще всего данная роль установлена на том же сервере что и сервер терминалов).
   b. Вызвать 'Диспетчер лицензирования удаленных рабочих столов' (`%windir%\system32\licmgr.msc`).
   c. Выбрать в открывшейся консоли сервер лицензий. Посмотреть установленные лицензии, проверить статус сервера лицензий (активирован или нет);
2. для подключения к серверу в режиме 'консоль' выполнить с повышением прав от имени администратора: `mstsc /v:[TERMINAL_SERVER] /admin`; подключение к серверу терминалов выполнять от пользователя с правами администратора терминального сервера/администратора домена;

   - вместо [TERMINAL_SERVER] указать имя сервера. пробовать подключаться с полным доменным именем и/или ip-адресом
3. В дополнение к приведенным действия по удалению ключей лицензии на проблемной рабочей станции после очистки запустить mstsc c повышенными правами+правами администратора.

Answer (score 0):

На некоторых Windows 10 удаление "MSLicensing" не работает, если использовать утилиту «Подключение к рабочему столу». Хоть за удаляйся «MSLicensing». Проверял на лицензионной Windows 10 Pro подключаться к Windows Server 2012, с купленными лицензиями на удаленный доступ. В таких случаях на Windows 10 нужно использовать утилиту «Удаленный рабочий стол» как тут (https://windowstips.ru/udalennyj-rabochij-stol-v-windows-10-i-8-1), вот на ней всё начинает работать, после удаления MSLicensing.